# TestNG - parallel Test execution, WebDriver nullpointer

Tags: java, webdriver, testng, thread-local, parallels

I am sure it has to be an easy one to solve but nothing comes to my mind at this moment, here is the situation.

I have one Singleton class (DriverFactory.class) to set and retrieve a ThreadLocal Object.
Two test classes running in parallel (FirstTestClass), (SecondTestClass)
and the third TestListenerAdapter class with a method where I want to use the actual running WebDriver instance(it should be bound to the Thread) but here I am getting null pointer exception even if, here is the code

```java
import config.DriverFactory;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class SecondTestClass {

    WebDriver driver;

    public SecondTestClass()throws Exception{
        DriverFactory.getInstance().setDriver();
        driver = DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver();;
    }

    @Test
    public void testInSecondClass() {
        System.out.println("\n THREAD ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + "\n Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        driver.get("https://www.allsaints.com");
        System.out.println("CURRENT URL IS :" + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        Assert.assertTrue(false);

    }
}
```

```java
package testParallel;

import config.DriverFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class FirstTestClass {

    WebDriver driver;

    public FirstTestClass()throws Exception{
        DriverFactory.getInstance().setDriver();
        driver = DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver();;
    }

    @Test
    public void testInFirstClass() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("\n THREAD ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " + "\n Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        DriverFactory.getInstance().setDriver();
        driver = DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver();;
        driver.get("https://pl.wikipedia.org");
        System.out.println("CURRENT URL IS :" + driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }
}
```

```java
package config;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DriverFactory {

    private static DriverFactory instance = null;

    public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    private DriverFactory() {}

    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    public static DriverFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DriverFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public final void setDriver() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Projects\\allsaints\\tess\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        webDriver.set(new FirefoxDriver());
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() throws Exception {
        return webDriver.get();
    }
}
```

```java
import config.DriverFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;

public class testSetup extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        System.out.println(
                "\n THREAD ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " +
                        "\n Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()

        );
        WebDriver driver;
        try {
             driver = DriverFactory.getInstance().getDriver();
            System.out.println("CURRENT URL IS :" + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onTestFailure(tr);
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<suite name="All Test Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="testParallel.testSetup"/>
    </listeners>
    <test verbose="3" preserve-order="true" name="test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="testParallel.FirstTestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="testParallel.SecondTestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Console output

> class testParallel.FirstTestClass  THREAD ID: 22   Name: TestNG
>
> class testParallel.SecondTestClass  THREAD ID: 23   Name: TestNG
>
> class testParallel.testSetup  THREAD ID: 23   Name: TestNG
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   testParallel.testSetup.onTestFailure(testSetup.java:21)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1895)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1879)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:778)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)  at
>   org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) CURRENT URL IS
>   :https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Strona_g%C5%82%C3%B3wna

Answer (score 1):

In Listeners, we can't directly access other class instance.Since,It will start listen when the execution begins. If we need to get some particular class instance, then we can access through TestNG Listeners(`ITestResult`) as below and all your test class should be inherited the `DriverFactory` class .

**Listener Class Code:**

```
public class testSetup extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        System.out.println(
                "\n THREAD ID: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " " +
                        "\n Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()

        );

        Object currentClass=tr.getInstance();

        WebDriver driver;
        try {
             driver =((DriverFactory) currentClass).getDriver();
            System.out.println("CURRENT URL IS :" + driver.getCurrentUrl());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onTestFailure(tr);
    }

}
```

**Test Class 1:**

```
public class FirstTestClass extends DriverFactory {

    WebDriver driver;
```

**Test Class 2:**

```
public class SecondTestClass extends DriverFactory {

    WebDriver driver;
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate :)

Comment: Glad to know, it is helpful. Please consider to accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark below the down arrow button.